# Why are values passed through useless copies?

Tags: linux, x86-64

So, say that I have the following code, which gives three examples of what I believe to be unnecessary copies of values.

```
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
mov    rsi,rdx
mov    rdi,rax
call   4003e0 <strcpy@plt>
```

Why is the value in `rdi` copied to memory at `rbp-0x18`, then copied back to `rdx` ?  It's then copied to `rsi` (2 extra copies).

Finally, why the `lea + mov` for `rbp-0x10` to `rax`, then to `rdi` ?  Is there any reason the following code wasn't generated ?

```
mov    rsi,rdi
lea    rdi,[rbp-0x10]
call   4003e0 <strcpy@plt>
```

(My guess is that this is just an artifact of the code generation in the compiler, but I'm making sure there's not some rules of x86-64 that I'm missing.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no artifacts and surely the compiler, and I mean `GCC`, can generate a better and faster code if told so. The first version of your generated code is non optimized. Why ? Either because `-O0` flag (0 level optimizations ==> No optimizations) was specified, or because no optimization flags were specified and by default `GCC` turns optimizations off.

Below you'll find two versions of the same code. Version 1 with `-O0` flag. Version 2 with `-O2` flag.

- **Version 1:**

  ```
   55                      push   rbp
   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   48 81 ec 10 04 00 00    sub    rsp,0x410
   89 bd fc fb ff ff       mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x404],edi
   48 89 b5 f0 fb ff ff    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x410],rsi
   48 8b 85 f0 fb ff ff    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x410]
   48 83 c0 08             add    rax,0x8
   48 8b 10                mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
   48 8d 85 00 fc ff ff    lea    rax,[rbp-0x400]
   48 89 d6                mov    rsi,rdx
   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
   e8 40 fe ff ff          call   400400 <strcpy@plt>
   48 8d 85 00 fc ff ff    lea    rax,[rbp-0x400]
   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
   e8 41 fe ff ff          call   400410 <puts@plt>
   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   c9                      leave
   c3                      ret
   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
   00 00 00
  ```
- **Version 2:**

  ```
   48 81 ec 08 04 00 00    sub    rsp,0x408
   48 8b 76 08             mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rsi+0x8]
   48 89 e7                mov    rdi,rsp
   e8 ad ff ff ff          call   400400 <strcpy@plt>
   48 89 e7                mov    rdi,rsp
   e8 b5 ff ff ff          call   400410 <puts@plt>
   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
   48 81 c4 08 04 00 00    add    rsp,0x408
   c3                      ret
   0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
  ```

If you're interested in the optimizations performed by `GCC` you should read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) link, and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Optimization-Levels.html) one too. You can also check the [`GCC` summit publications](ftp://ftp.uvsq.fr/pub/gcc/summit/).

Comment: Ok, seems to be what I was assuming.  I was posting code from a wargame challenge, and I suppose no optimization makes sense there.